# Why did Barry Seal record his yearly actions?

Tags: plot-explanation, american-made

In *American Made*, why did Seal record his yearly actions working from the CIA to the Cartel.

What is its purpose?

I ask this question because he did not do anything to protect the tapes since he put them in the back of his trunk then try to start his car (maybe rigged to explode).

Or like what happened in the movie. He died and the tapes were confiscated and never been submitted to evidence.